# AJAX and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm building a web application in CodeIgniter and I'm using jQuery and AJAX. I created the whole app locally (using XAMPP) and everything worked fine. After I uploaded the app to my web hosting, one AJAX keeps failing. Here is the part of the code:

```
// Get all form inputs
var inputs = $('#app-options-existing-form :input[type="text"]');

// Put them in object as name=>value
var data = {};

for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    data[inputs[i]["name"]] = inputs[i]["value"];
}

// Put loader while AJAX is working
$(".app-content-container").html('<center><img class="loader" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/img/loader.gif" ></center>');

console.log(data);

// Generate POST request
$.post("<?php echo site_url("admin/ajax_app_options"); ?>",
{"add_existing_form_submited" : true, "data" : data2},
function (data) {
    alert("test" + data);       
});
```

Here's the console showing error and result of console.log(data)
[image: Error and result of console.log(data)]

First, I thought that the key ("d1d1d1") was the problem because I was first using "1-1-1" and after I manually changed it, it was working. But then I changed everything in "d1d1d1" and it doesn't work again. As I said, it works on XAMPP but not on server. Can be a problem in using full URL for AJAX, instead of relative one? But I'm using it in other AJAX requests as well and it works.

Comment: Suggest checking the network tab of the browser debugger. It will display all the details about the ajax request.  And from that the problem will probably be obvious. For example, are the url and data what you expected?

Comment: Oh, sorry for me being stupid. I didn't even know for the Network tab :) Every time I had some problem with AJAX, I would debug it manually by displaying given errors but this time, since it was a 500 error, I was not able to do so. After I took a look on Network tab, there I was able to see a Codeigniter error because I was using a wrong table name in database.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you problem is this guy `'<center><img class="loader" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/img/loader.gif" ></center>'`

Yours source is going to output literally to `<?php echo base_url();?>/img/loader.gif` which is of course not a real link. Therefore it is a resource that can not be loaded.

You might want to try instead using: `'<center><img class="loader" src="/img/loader.gif" ></center>'`

The `base_url()` function is just going to return '/' anyway.

**Important!** In general you can not write php in javascript. Or this would be a massive security hole that would give every user who visits your site unlimited access to your server.

Comment: Javascript code is inside a PHP file so this function works properly. How can somebody gain access to my server with this?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure I understand your use case. A typical website uses javscript client side and php server side. If you're using javascript server side I don't understand what your code is supposed to be doing (ajax would be pointless). If you are indeed using javascript client side then the abiliy to put `<?php whatever php I want'?>` in a javascript file and have it execute means I can do anything including sql injection, php injection, full file access etc. Simply by writing the browser console. I don't think any browser allows that though. Which is why your code doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with Codeigniter. If you are, I'm using Javascript as a view. So, every Javascript, instead in a separate .js file, is located in PHP file which represents a view. The content of this file is echoed to the <head></head> part of the main view. So, when you're looking at the source code, you won't see src="<?php echo base_url();?>/img/loader.gif" but you will instead see src="http://www.example.com/img/loader.gif" .

Comment: Oh, fun. I'm not familiar with code igniter (didn't see that tag). But it sounds like code igniter is like a template engine for javascript. Sorry to waste your time with all that. In this case I don't think you have given enough data. 500 means the page was found, but some error prevented it from generating it's output. A parse error would trigger this. Look at the code generating the ajax response not the code making the ajax call.

Comment: No problem :) Thank you for your help. Codeigniter is a framework based on MVC pattern for PHP. I found a problem, and it's me being stupid :) I left detailed solution as an answer in above comment on my original question.